# Is there a way to check for empty arrays returned from ActiveRecord queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to write an activerecord query that behaves something like this:

```
User.joins(:comment).where(comments: {replies: []})
```

which returns Users where their comments have no replies.

```
User.first.comment.first.replies => [] returns an empty array
```

I need this to be an activerecord relation only, so using ruby code won't work. Is there a way to check for empty arrays using activerecord?

Edit:
Example schema

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "email",
t.string "password"
end

create_table "comments" do |t|
t.string "content"
end

create_table "replies" do |t|
t.string "content"
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments
end
```

Comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :replies
end
```

Reply.rb

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :comment
belongs_to :user
end
```

These are just example models but this should illustrate the problem with models associated this these.

So if a user(with id of 1) has made 3 comments, and only 1 of those 3 comments has a reply on it, how would I get the other 2 comments in an activerecord relation?

Comment: Could you post the schema for the comments table please?

Comment: The models that I used were just examples, but I can create a example schema with those models if that's helpful.

Comment: I was mostly keen to get a grasp on the replies column and how it's stored (/ if I'm misunderstanding and it's another table). I can give you a hacky example of how to get this working for the time being, but to get the optimal approach I'd need a little more on how the data's stored. Edit: also be good to get the model structure and how the tables are associated.

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes and I'll edit that in

Comment: Is there and `ActiveRecord::Relation` defined between `comment` and `replies`, i.e. `has_many :replies` in the `Comment` model?  Or is `replies` a column on `comments` which is stored as array/JSON?

Comment: Yes, comment has_many replies. I added example models above

Comment: @JimmyW Please see my answer.  It provides a solution using only an `ActiveRecord` query and no additional dependencies as requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make design more simple by using counter_cache

Add counter_cache in replies

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :comment, counter_cache: true
belongs_to :user
end
```

Add counter column in comment table

```
create_table "comments" do |t|
t.string "content"
t.integer "replies_count"
end
```

Simple use condition for replies_count

```
User.joins(:comment).where(comments: {replies_count: 0})
```

For more info refer to [rails doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` from `comments` to `replies` which will return all comments regardless of whether or not there was a reply for every comment.  The usual join in rails, i.e. join executed when you do `@comment.replies` or `User.joins(comments: :replies)` is an `INNER JOIN`.  `ActiveRecord` doesn't have a nifty DSL for writing left join queries, but does allow them in the following way:

```
# Find all users who have at least one comment with no replies
User.joins(:comments)
  .joins("LEFT JOIN replies ON replies.comment_id = comments.id")
  .where("replies.id IS NULL")

# Find all comments for a user that don't have replies
@user.comments
  .joins("LEFT JOIN replies ON replies.comment_id = comments.id")
  .where("replies.id IS NULL")
```

I included the two snippets because in your question it was unclear if you wanted to find the users or the comments for a certain user with no replies.

The `where("replies.id IS NULL")` is the filter which finds every comment in the `LEFT JOIN` with no  matching replies, and delivers the result you want.  This is a very common `SQL` trick worth keeping in mind for future data digging.